# Is it possible to achieve 4G/LTE environment without buying local SIM?

Tags: cellphones, data-plans, roaming

I cannot tolerate slow network in traveling and want to always get the fast network environment, possibly >5MB constantly. However, at the same time I don't like to buy local SIM card whenever I enter a next country.

So I ended up with considering my carrier's roaming plan, but it is quit expensive (around US$25 per day!). And then, I ended up with switching to international SIM, which I have just knew.

However, as long as I search for it, it doesn't seem to be what I want. Specifically, most of it lack phone number (some have) and does neither have fixed usage data plan nor tethering. Also, the network speed doesn't seem to be what they focus on, as they don't mention it at all.

So I just want to use my phone the same way I use it in my home country, like:

- Have one phone number
- Fixed monthly data plan, conform to 4G/LTE
- Tethering

And for your information my usage prediction is the following:

- 1GB per month (although I might want 2GB)
- Only receive a few SMS per month
- Won't make nor receive call

Another option is rental mobile router. However, I don't like the option because it forces me to carry one more gadget in traveling.

Is there any option available to meet my needs? Or if the speed is my top priority should I bother to purchase local SIM? It is what I'm desperately looking for, and thus I can even spend US$ 100+ monthly.

---

#### UPDATE

The country/city I plan to travel is the following:

- Top priority: Shanghai, Beijing, Hong Kong, Seoul, Singapore
- Next priority: Moscow, Australia, Italy (mostly North), Spain, Stockholm, London, Kuala Lumpur, Canada

Comment: Which country or countries do you plan to travel? The whole of the world is likely too broad for a question here.

Comment: @Willeke My bad. Updated.

Comment: It seems like what you want is roaming, but cheaper than your current provider offers it.  So I think all you can really do is shop the various providers in your home country.  That turns this into a shopping question, for which Stack Exchange is not the right place.

Comment: @NateEldredge What I want is get the fast network environment, irrespective of whether it is roaming by my carrier or not. Also, all the carriers in my home country provide exactly the same plan, so I don't have any choices.

Answer (score 4):

T-Mobile has a unlimited-data-in-120+-countries plan that should cover all your countries. I have that plan since two years, and it worked smoothless (and cost-free) in India, Russia, all of Western Europe, Czechia, the Carribean, Mexico, Canada and the US.

Note that some countries or areas do not have 4G/LTE, and no matter what you buy or do, you will not get 4G/LTE speed there.

Comment: While T-Mobile USA will connect to LTE roaming services in many countries the free data service is severely speed limited, often down to 128 kbps. They will remove the speed constraint for a price of $50/500 MB. Since the question explicitly asks for high speed data the up-charge probably needs to be included in the accounting.

Comment: I use TMobile and despite their pretty lame coverage in USA, i'm very happy with them in other regards. they are more customer friendly than the others here IMO.